# How to debug a fastcgi script?

Tags: c++, debugging, fastcgi

I have a fastcgi script I wrote in C++ with the help of [fastcgi++](https://github.com/eddic/fastcgipp) library. I recently made a change to my script which causes a test to fail. How do I debug that script?

I found on the internet that one way to do it is to write an infinite loop in the code and then attach the debugger to the process and use the debugger to break out of the loop but it seems little off. There must be a better way!

I am using Fedora 30. And the script is on localhost and not a server

Comment: Visual Studio since 2017 has support for linux projects over SSH.

Comment: The problem is I only have one computer dual booted with Windows and Fedora. And my machine is a low end one. I cannot afford an emulator running @MichaelChourdakis

Comment: One thing I've done in the past is to put a `raise(SIGSTOP);` into the cgi program at some suitable place. Trigger it to run, and when it stops attach a debugger to the stopped process, then send it a SIGCONT signal from a different shell (using `kill -CONT pid_of_process`) after having set some breakpoints in the debugger (`gdb`). Then drive it from the debugger from there.